# How to access the dependency of a jar instead of writing the package names again the gradle kotlin?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, build.gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

#### Issue

Currently, I have a jar file as a common module for other spring boot applications which I would like to use for scanning.

`app.build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencies {
    api("com.company.app:appbase:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

I was not able to use the dependencies of the `com.company.app.appbase`, other than the base package itself, which shows errors like `Unresolved reference: springframework`

`base-package.build.gradle.kts`

```kotlin
dependencies{
   implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:3.0.5")
   ... // Spring boot dependencies
}
```

How could I use the dependencies, e.g. `io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging` without importing it in `app.build.gradle.kts`?

Thank you.

---

#### Attempts

I have tried using `implementation` and `api` commands in the `app.build.gradle.kts` file but the results are the same.

Comment: That's not how it works. If you have local projects A and B, and a Gradle dependency from A on B, then all `api` dependencies in B will also be available in A, but `implementation` dependencies will not.

Comment: I tried changing to `api` dependency instead of `implementation` in the base package, and it works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want transitive dependencies access, in this case you need to do the modifications not in the `app.build.gradle.kts` but in your `com.company.app.appbase` build script `build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    api("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:3.0.5")
}
```

Then by doing in the `app.build.gradle.kts`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.company.app:appbase:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT")
}
```

`microutils` should be then available without mentioning it.

Check doc:
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html#sec:java_library_separation